# Returning PHP multidimensional array value

Tags: php

I'm returning array data from another service.
The data I got after JSON decode is like this

```
Array
(
    [result] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [number] => INC00001234
                    [short_description] => LLKS portal outage 
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [number] => INC00001235
                    [short_description] => Server degradation
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [number] => INC00001236
                    [short_description] => Printer not printing
                )
        )
)
```

Now, all I wanted is to loop through the JSON and list just the numbers like this

```
Number : INC00001234
Description : LLKS portal outage 

Number : INC00001235
Description : Server degradation

Number : INC00001236
Description : Printer not printing
```

How do I do that?

Comment: `foreach ($arr['result'] as &$value) {
    print("Number: " . $value['number']);
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that your JSON's datas are in a variable. I used `$data` below, but you need to use yours.

```
foreach($data['result'] as $line){
    echo 'Number : ' . $line['number'] . '<br/>\nDescription : ' . $line['short_description'] . '<br/>\n';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($yourArray['result'] as $item){
   echo "\nNumber:{$item['number']}\nDescription:{$item['short_description']}\n";
}
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should explain **what** the code does and **how** it helps